# Accessing inner variables of parameter pack in C++

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, variadic-templates

Is there any simple method for accessing inner members of whole parameter pack? Lets say you have following code

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
    typedef int type;
    constexpr static type C = 5;
};

class B {
    typedef unsigned type;
    constexpr static type C = 6;
};

template <class T1, class ... TList>
std::ostream & printer(std::ostream & out, T1 t1, TList ... plist) {
    out << t1 << " ";
    return printer(out, plist...);
}

template <class T1>
std::ostream & printer(std::ostream & out, T1 t1) {
    return out << t1 << std::endl;
}

template <class ... TList>
std::ostream & proxy(std::ostream & out, TList ... plist) {
    return printer(out, std::forward<TList::type ...>(plist::C ...));
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    proxy(std::cout, A(), B());
    return 0;
}
```

I want proxy function to unpack member variables of plist and pass them to printer. Is there a simple way how to do this without iterating through parameter list?

Comment: How would you determine which member you want to print?

Comment: Member C in every variable in pack. I tried to point this using plist::C ... which is not correct according to clang

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought you meant you want to print _only some_ of the elements in the pack. But you want to print them all -- but just the member called `C` in each of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After clearing several issues with your code, i could make it compile:

- `A` and `B` should be structs to make their definitions public.
- there is no sense in forwarding their static members, just skip the forwarding - forwarding makes sense for "universal references" only
- In gcc, I had to put the one-argument `printer` before the variadic one

proxy now looks like this:

```
template <class ... TList>
std::ostream & proxy(std::ostream & out, TList ... plist) {
  //leave the forward, plist is a variable pack, so operator.
  return printer(out, plist.C ...);  

  //or:
  return printer(out, TList::C...); 
}
```

And since the `C`'s are static constexpr members, you can just leave the argument pack:

```
template <class ... TList>
std::ostream & proxy(std::ostream & out) {
    return printer(out, TList::C ...);  
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    proxy<A,B>(std::cout);
    return 0;
}
```

FYI, the correct call to `std::forward` would have looked like this, if `C` was an ordinary member variable of A and B:

```
template <class ... TList>
std::ostream & proxy(std::ostream & out, TList&& ... plist) {
    return printer(out, std::forward<typename TList::type>(plist.C)...);
}
```

Comment: I was gonna post mostly the same :)